# How can I use getSupportLoaderManager() in Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I want to load information from an API to a `Fragment`.

I use `getSupportLoaderManager()` but an error is occurring:

> Cannot resolve method: getSupportLoaderManager()

I search for this use `onActivityCreated()` but I have `NullPointerException`.

Can you help me to solve the issue?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Business extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {

    ListView listView;   

    public Business() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business, container, false);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, getContext()).forceLoad();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty())
            updateUI(data);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {

    }

    private void updateUI(String data) {
        try {
            final ArrayList<ResultOfArtBusiness> results = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONObject secondObject = root.getJSONObject("response");

            JSONArray firstArray = secondObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject objectInArray = firstArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String webPublicationDate;
                if (objectInArray.has("webPublicationDate"))
                    webPublicationDate =   objectInArray.getString("webPublicationDate");
                else webPublicationDate = null;

                String webTitle;
                if (objectInArray.has("webTitle"))
                    webTitle = objectInArray.getString("webTitle");
                else webTitle = null;

                String webUrl;
                if (objectInArray.has("webUrl"))
                    webUrl = objectInArray.getString("webUrl");
                else webUrl = null;

                ResultOfArtBusiness resultOfArticle = new ResultOfArtBusiness(webTitle, webPublicationDate, webUrl);
                results.add(resultOfArticle);
            }

            NewsAdapterBusiness adapter = new NewsAdapterBusiness(getContext(), R.layout.item_design, results);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I search about this use onActivityCreated"? I can't see any code for `onActivityCreated()`, so I don't understand this part of your question.

Comment: I mean I searched for the issue I have found that I have to override the onActivityCreated() and in that method I should write getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, getContext()).forceLoad(); I wrote that but I have Null pointer exception.

Comment: All right. If you want to find out why you got a NPE you'll have to share the error message from Logcat. Then maybe one can see what exactly was null.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.content.Loader.forceLoad()' on a null object reference

Comment: at com.example.hp.newnewsapp.Fragment.Business.onActivityCreated(Business.java:44)

Comment: So obviously the Loader wasn't created. Maybe because the third parameter ought to be a `LoaderCallbacks<D> callback` and you used `getContext()`?  Another thing: I'm wondering whether calling `forceLoad()` at this point is a good idea: "You generally should only call this when the loader is started -- that is, isStarted() returns true. " (quoted from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#forceLoad()))

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** Sept 2, 2019

`getLoaderManager()` in `Fragment` is deprecated.

use

```
// LoaderManager#getInstance(LifecycleOwner) 
LoaderManager.getInstance(this) // this points to the Fragment
```

---

**Old Answer**

The thing is that we use `getLoaderManager()` or `getSupportLoaderManager()` when calling from activity but **when it comes to fragment you can directly call `getLoaderManager()`** no need to call `getSupportLoaderManager()` and behind the scenes it will call its respective versions of the method depending upon the fragment used.

Comment: I have error with that also the error is Can not resolve method getLoaderFragment.

Comment: as I have mentioned we can call getLoaderManager and it will work for both fragment type and it's working for me now it's hard to tell why it's not  getting resolved for you.

Comment: There is no such method getSupportLoaderManager () for support fragment.

Comment: I changed to getLoaderManager() but I have Exception and this is the exception.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.content.Loader.forceLoad()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.hp.newnewsapp.Fragment.Business.onCreateView(Business.java:49)

Comment: i am using LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this); inside fragment class But i have same nullpointer exception any solution?